# Deploying Java project to Heroku without Maven-supported dependencies

Tags: java, maven, heroku

Is anyone working with Heroku for Java?

I have one Java project which I want to deploy on Heroku. That project uses some external JAR files which contains important dependencies.

Can anyone tell me how to deploy my project with these JAR files to Heroku?  Maven is not able to download these JAR files on Heroku.

Comment: Did you check out this link - http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java#deploy_to_herokucedar , and follow steps as mentioned?

Comment: yes i checked  but there is nothing releted to same . they just mantioned deployment of simple helloworld  nothing else

Comment: related discussion: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java/issues/7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We just published a guide showing how to add dependencies like this to your project:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: i have already finished up this problem before publishing on heroku devcenter . can we connect to heroku using webservices or anything else . i want to set up an integration in java which should login in ito heroku and run my application.?

Comment: Cool. Can you vote up one of the answers if it solves the problem so others can find it? (I saw you asked the web services question in a separate question and will expect you to get an answer there).

Comment: Jesper, would be much more convenient if you allow users to put `settings.xml` to the same root folder, right to `pom.xml`. Then, during Maven execution you can use this file as a custom settings file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a local Maven repository containing your jars.  Include that repo in your git repo.  And add the repo to the `pom.xml` file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-libs-dir</id>
        <name>locallib</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/libs</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The jar files must be in the standard Maven repo layout and have md5 & sha1 checksums.

Comment: hi james , i m faceing problem to understand what to do next. can i contact you to resolve this problem . i added system dependency in my pom.xml now it is compiling my code  but when i m trying to run it in heroku it is giving "NoClassDefFoundException"  could not find the main class

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin/index.html), which automates the entire deployment process:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <name>my-test-app</name>
      <artifacts>
        <artifact>com.example:example-app:jar::${project.version}</artifact>
      </artifacts>
      <procfile>web: java -Xmx256m -jar ./example-app.jar \${PORT}</procfile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Besides that, you have to deploy your artifact (JAR/WAR) to your repository, so that Maven inside Heroku can download it during deployment.

Comment: While your project looks really promising, this excerpt: "[Then, make sure your Maven deploy goal deploys said WAR/JAR package to a repository available in Internet.](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-heroku-maven-plugin/example-start.html)" implies this is not what this question is looking for.

Comment: Make a private Amazon S3 repository and deploy there, why not?